# Syncing files not in Desktop / Documents via iCloud

Tags: icloud, macos, backup

I have a folder containing scripts and files they operate on in a root folder /data. I would like to have them automatically backed-up as they get updated but I can't move them out of /data, as that's the folder most scripts use to locate their files. Is there a way to do this?

I use macOS Sierra Version 10.12.4. Thanks!

Comment: I don't use iCloud for documents, so I can't test this, but have you experimented by putting an alias, (or by creating a hard link,) to this folder in the Documents folder to see if iCloud will back it up that way? Just a thought

Comment: @IconDaemon thanks for you comment! It's a great idea, but unfortunately aliases / symlinks don't work with iCloud, and hard links have serious [problems](https://superuser.com/questions/139390/hard-link-not-works-under-mac-os-x-in-gui-mode/139391) when used with GUI.

Answer (score 2):

I've come up with two solutions:

1. Using Google's Backup-and-Sync app, which allows you to select which folders to automatically sync with Google Drive (this doesn't use iCloud through)
2. Using cron, a MacOS / Linux command-line program, to automatically [rsync](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) your directory outside of iCloud path and its copy in the iCloud folder.